# Ubuntu18.04 desktop amd64 does not recognise Acer Inspire S3 touchpad button

Tags: drivers, 18.04, touchpad

I just install or try the Ubuntu 18.04 desktop amd64
on my Acer Inspire S3 .
When I use the  (in ms windows = file manager) to copy files,
ubuntu18.04 does not recognise my laptop touchpad's  <kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Left</kbd> buttons.

Does not show up the [copy/paste/move/...] menu after pressing the touchpad <kbd>Right</kbd> button. There is no way to copy and paste files.

I have to use Ubuntu 16.04 and it works perfectly or I have to plug an external USB mouse and it also works fine.

I think the ubuntu18.04 desktop amd64 touchpad driver does not support Acer S3 Laptop.

Please give me suggestions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is not driver issue but default touchpad settings. 
Go to `Mouse and Touchpad` in `Settings`. Increase touchpad speed and disable Natural scrolling.

You need to install gnome-tweaks.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

You can change default behavior.  You need to change settings from `Keyboard & mouse` >> `Mouse Click Emulations` >> `Area`